# How to trigger error and test the method?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jestjs, jasmine-marbles

I am doing angular service test. it works fine. But I unable to achieve the 100% of testing, since the error function not tested. I tried my best. but not able to come up with 100%. any one help me?

here is my service:

```
export class CandidateRegistrationManagementService {

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

    getAvailabilityType(): Observable<ModelAvailabilityType> {
        return this.http.get<ModelAvailabilityType>(environment.setUpAndConfigUrl + `LookupTypeValue/LookupValueTypeDetails?LookupTypeName=AvailabilityType`)
            .pipe(
                map(events => {
                    return events;
                }),
                catchError(this.handleError)
            );
    }
    
    handleError(error: Response) {
        return throwError(error);
    }
}
```

my test case at present 75% i have covered. problem to with error testing. here is my try:

```
it('should throw error', () => {

        const httpError = {
            get: jest.fn(() => of(hot('#', {}, new Error('server error'))))
        };

        function handleError(error:any) {
            return throwError(error);
        }

        CRMService = new CandidateRegistrationManagementService(httpError as any);
        CRMService.getAvailabilityType().subscribe(data =>data, (error:any) => {
            catchError(handleError(error))
        })

    })
```

But my try not works. I am not get 100% of coverage. please looking for an help here.

Comment: Have you tried https://angular.io/guide/http#testing-for-errors? But note that `catchError((err) => throwError(err))` is effectively a no-op, there's no point catching it to start with.

Comment: @jonrsharpe - but I am not able to get 100% coverage, until i complete my test with error.

Comment: You could improve your coverage without writing an error test if you *removed the redundant error path*. Again, though, if you do want to test the error case have you tried using the tools Angular provides for testing HTTP services?

Comment: @jonrsharpe - I agree with you. let me try for angular recommendation. but the thing is I use jest.js with jasmine-marbles. looking to fix the same way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using -- throwError rxjs operator,  throwError  will execute error block of your code.

```
   const httpError = {
            get: jest.fn(() => throwError(new Error('server error'))
        };
```